# why does this line of apply method not work in python

Tags: python, pandas, apply

```
data['age0'] = data['user_age_level'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 1004 | x == 1005 | x == 1006 | x == 1007  else 2)
```

Above is worked well, but

```
data['star0'] = data['user_star_level'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == -1 | x == 3000 | x == 3001  else 2)
```

not work.

I'm try to print info, like this:

```
print(sum(data['user_star_level'] == -1))
print(data[['user_star_level', 'star0']][0:6])
print(data['user_star_level'].dtype)
```

and it turns out:

```
982
   user_star_level  star0
0             3003      2
1             3006      2
2             3004      2
3             3006      2
4             3001      2
5             3002      2
int64
```

Comment: You just need to check `isin` function

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? What did it look like in the beginning?

Comment: Not entirely related to your question, but you should be aware that `|` is the *bitwise* or operator. The *logical* or operator is called `or`. It works in your case because the bitwise or operator evaluates booleans as `0` and `1` and `if` interprets `1` as `True` and `0` as `False`, so it is functionally equivalent in your case. But just fyi, as that can be an easy mistake to make in cases where it would make a difference.

Comment: I want use second code to classify 'user_star_level', when value is -1,3000,3001, 'star0' should be 1. 
but, index 4 print '4  3001  2', that means the second code is not work.
and, I don't know why. @OneRaynyDay

Comment: you're telling me! That's the point why it doesn't work. @Zinki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asides from your specific problem, you should in general try to avoid using `apply`, as it is *very* slow. You probably meant something similar to the following:

```
import numpy as np

data['star0'] = np.where(data['user_star_level'].isin([-1, 3000, 2]), 1, 2)
```

- `data['user_star_level'].isin([-1, 3000, 2])` uses [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to check if the value of the series is in the list.
- [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is the vectorized version of `x if y else z`.

Comment: Thank you, how could you know which is slow or not? Could you recommend some books or website?